# Nextjs different slug names for the same dynamic path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

This is my folder structure of my nextjs app and Iam getting this error: `Failed to reload dynamic routes: Error: You cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path ('_Id' !== 'id').`

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

[image: folder structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after wasting 1 hour, I killed the server and reran it. All good now.

Comment: Kill my own server didn't fix my problem :(